# Convert tensorflow model(.pb) to coreml(.mlmodel)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, coreml

## ValueError: No op found in the TF graph that produces the given output name(s)

*Am totally new to ML/Tensorflow as well as Python.*

I am trying to convert a model from .pb format to .mlmodel format to be used in an ios project.
I am using tf-coreml for it.

```
>>> tf_converter.convert(tf_model_path = '/Users/anup/Downloads/inception_v1_2016_08_28_frozen.pb/inception_v1_2016_08_28_frozen.pb',mlmodel_path = '/Users/anup/Downloads/inception_v1_2016_08_28_frozen.pb/inception_v1_2016_08_28_frozen.mlmodel',output_feature_names = ['Softmax:0'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py", line 493, in convert
    predicted_probabilities_output=predicted_probabilities_output)
  File "tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py", line 157, in _convert_pb_to_mlmodel
    OPS, skip_ops = _topological_sort_ops(OPS, output_feature_names) # do (1),(2),(3) listed above
  File "tfcoreml/_tf_graph_transform.py", line 134, in _topological_sort_ops
    skip_ops = _find_skippable_ops(G, ops, output_names)
  File "tfcoreml/_tf_graph_transform.py", line 72, in _find_skippable_ops
    raise ValueError('No op found in the TF graph that produces the given output name(s)')
ValueError: No op found in the TF graph that produces the given output name(s)
>>>
```

Am running this on mac terminal.
Actually i don't know what Softmax:0 mean and whether i need to replace it with something else.Following this: https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml
It might be a pretty simple thing and am being stupid.Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

`Softmax:0` is the name of a tensor. It appears that your graph does not have a tensor with that name.

One way to find the name of the last tensor in your graph is to [download Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/Netron/blob/master/README.md) and use it to view the `.pb` file.

Comment: I converted the file following this: https://hackernoon.com/integrating-tensorflow-model-in-an-ios-app-cecf30b9068d But when i imported to ios project, it was not accepting images.

Comment: I think the last tensor graph : 559: op name = import/final_result, op type = ( Softmax ), inputs = import/final_training_ops/Wx_plus_b/add:0, outputs = import/final_result:0
@ input shapes:
name = import/final_training_ops/Wx_plus_b/add:0 : (?, 5)
@ output shapes:
name = import/final_result:0 : (?, 5)